# Why is the pointer not accessible outside of this function after using malloc?

Tags: c, scope, malloc

This is a fairly simple question about malloc and scope. From my understanding of malloc, it allows you to dynamically allocate memory for variables etc. Shouldn't this mean that the variable remains accessible until the memory is freed? I wrote a couple lines of code but I run into this error when I try to compile.

Error message:
"malloc.c:16:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'a'"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* createnum(int n)
{
    int* a = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *a = n;
    printf("%p\n", a);
    printf("%d\n", *a);
    return a;
}

int main(void)
{
    createnum(1);
    printf("The variable is %d\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `malloc`, just scope/name lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said,

> Shouldn't this mean that the variable remains accessible until the memory is freed?

That is not correct. The memory is accessible if it is returned from the function like you are but not the variable. The variable is accessible only in `createnum`.

You want something like:

```
int* a = createnum(1);
```

Of course, you'll have to change

```
printf("The variable is %d\n", a);
```

to

```
printf("The variable is %d\n", *a);
```

since type of `a` is `int*`, not `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this!

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int* createnum(int n)
    {
        int* a = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *a = n;
        printf("%p\n", a);
        printf("%d\n", *a);
        return a;
    }

    int main(void)
    {
        int *p = createnum(1);
        printf("The variable is %d\n", *p);
        free(p);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: @MattMcNabb How?I am curious.

Comment: @Vagish The version that was visible when I wrote that comment originally leaked memory!